# Storing generic collection in System.Runtime.Caching - List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using `System.Runtime.Caching` to store a `List<MyType>`. The problem is when I retrieve the collection it comes back as `System.Object`.

I have tried casting it back to `List<MyType>` with no luck.

if I try `as` I get a `null`

```
var siteNodes = _cacheManager.Get(Constants.CacheKeys.SiteNodesCacheKey) 
                as List<SiteNode>;
```

What is the proper way to store and retrieve my `List<MyType>` in cache?

I am using a cache manager class to access cache.

```
public void Add(string key, object data, int cacheTime,
                CacheEntryRemovedCallback callback)
    {
        _callback = callback;
        Add(key, data, cacheTime);
    }

public object Get(string key)
    {
        return Cache[key];
    }

var siteNodes = _cacheManager.Get(Constants.CacheKeys.SiteNodesCacheKey) 
                as List<SiteNode>;
```

Here is the method that adds to the cache

```
public void Add(string key, object data, int cacheTime, 
                CacheEntryRemovedCallback callback)
    {
        _callback = callback;
        Add(key, data, cacheTime);
    }
```

Here is the method that interacted with my cachemanager class.

```
private void CacheData(IEnumerable<object> data, string cacheKey)
    {
        if (_cacheManager.Contains(cacheKey))
        {
            _cacheManager.Remove(cacheKey);
        }

        _cacheManager.Add(cacheKey, data, DefaultCacheTime);

    }
```

The above method is the root of my problem, in an effort to keep my method reusable I have the first param as IEnumerable of object which is changing my data that is getting stored.

So I created the following override..

```
private void CacheData(List<SiteNode> data, string cacheKey)
    {
        if (_cacheManager.Contains(cacheKey))
        {
            _cacheManager.Remove(cacheKey);
        }

        _cacheManager.Add(cacheKey, data, DefaultCacheTime);

    }
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: you mean it does not comeback as list

Comment: show how you put `List<SiteNodes>` in the cache

Comment: Fixed typo.. SO chopped off my brackets.

Comment: When I get the cached list back it will not convert or cast back to List<SiteNodes>. I have the SiteNodes class decorated with the Serializable attributes

Comment: note that in order for `<` `>` to appear they generally must be formatted as code, either inline with backquotes (as I hvae added) or (as you have done) with four-space indentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could to hard-cast it like this:

```
var siteNodes = (List<SiteNode>)_cacheManager.Get(Constants.CacheKeys.SiteNodesCacheKey);
```

But this will also break if the cache has expired the object. Instead, you first need to test if null (or do a contains to see if it's in cache), then hard-cast:

```
List<SiteNode> siteNodes;

object cached_site_nodes = _cacheManager.Get(Constants.CacheKeys.SiteNodesCacheKey);

if (null != cached_site_nodes)
{
   siteNodes = (List<SiteNode)cached_site_nodes;
}
else
{
   siteNodes = new List<SiteNode>();
}
```

By using the 'as' keyword you are effectively testing if it the underlying object is of type List, and it returns null since `System.Runtime.Caching.ObjectCache` has no idea what the type is when in the cache.

Comment: I tried the cast already.. I'll try it your way and see if it works

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BukuCms.Core.Domain.Entities.SiteNode]'.

Comment: List<object> and not List<SiteNode>? Seems like there's a problem in the code that adds it to the cache.

Comment: see my edit.. i added the final method that adds to the cache.

Comment: I saw that, I meant the code that actually calls that Add method. I believe the problem is either that the key argument is not equal to Constants.CacheKeys.SiteNodesCacheKey or that the object data argument is being passed as List<object> and not List<SiteNode>

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me on this one! Your comments got me looking in the right place and I was able to resolve my issue (see edits). Great work.. thank you!

Comment: Casting `null` to anything doesn't cause an exception, it just results in `null` types to whatever you cast it to.  In fact, `null` can be cast to *any* type, no matter what.  You don't need to do the null check before you do the cast.  You may need to do one after the cast if it's important that it be non-null, but that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've just been battling with the same error. Fix for me was to hard cast the CacheItem.Value, not the CacheItem, e.g:

```
return (IEnumerable<ObjType>)MyCacheItem.Value;
```

not...

```
return (IEnumerable<ObjType>)MyCacheItem;
```

(which caused the exception).